# WPF TextBox ScrollToLine not updating if visible

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox

I have a Navigation-bar in my program that allows you to navigate the different sections in my TextBox, but the problem I have is that this doesn't work if the Text I am scrolling to is already visible on the screen.

Like in this example, if I try to jump from Section 1 to Section 3, it won't work as it's already visible.

[image: Example 1]

But, in this example if I jump to Section 3, it works fine as it's not already visible.

[image: Example 2]

The scrolling function I use is very simple:

```
if (nLine > 0 && nLine <= textBox.LineCount)
    textBox.ScrollToLine(nLine - 1);
```

I hope that someone can shed some light on an alternative solution that allows me to scroll  even if the text is already visible.

*Edit: Added solution.*

**This is a code snippet from my project.**

```
private static void ScrollToLineCallback(DependencyObject target, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var textBox = (TextBox)target;

    int newLineValue;
    if (Int32.TryParse(e.NewValue.ToString(), out newLineValue))
    {
        if (newLineValue > 0 && newLineValue <= textBox.LineCount) // Validate
        {
            textBox.ScrollToLine(newLineValue - 1); // Scroll to Line

            // Check and see if we are at the line we want.
            if (textBox.GetFirstVisibleLineIndex() <= newLineValue && textBox.GetLastVisibleLineIndex() >= newLineValue)
            {
                // If not lets move to the desired location
                int newLineCorrectionValue = newLineValue - textBox.GetFirstVisibleLineIndex() - 2; // How much further do we need to scroll down?

                for (int i = 0; i < newLineCorrectionValue; i++)
                {
                    textBox.LineDown(); // Scroll down
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The reason it is not working is that ScrollToLine does just what it says it does in the docu: "Scrolls the line at a specified line index into view.". This means, if it is already visible, it doesn't scroll!

Comment: Yep Thanks Daniel. While that may be the case I am trying to figure out a way around that, but I'll update to reflect that. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [GetCharacterIndexFromLineIndex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textbox.getcharacterindexfromlineindex.aspx) to get the index of the beginning of the desired line and then set the [CaretIndex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textbox.caretindex.aspx) to that value.

Because I don't really know, what you are trying to achieve, another possibility is to use [LineUp](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.textboxbase.lineup.aspx) and [LineDown](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.textboxbase.linedown.aspx) in conjunction with [GetFirstVisibleLineIndex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textbox.getfirstvisiblelineindex.aspx) and [GetLastVisibleLineIndex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textbox.getlastvisiblelineindex.aspx).

Comment: I am basically allowing the user to use the Navigation bar to scroll to a specific section of a Text document. To make it easier for the user I always want the Section to be at the top of the document. It might be worth mentioning that the navigation bar item only contains the line and the name of the section.

Comment: I was able to get a working solution using your second suggestion. Cheers. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
private void TextBoxGotoLine(
    TextBox textbox1, 
    int linenum)
{
  var target_cpos = textbox1.GetCharacterIndexFromLineIndex(linenum);
  var target_char_rect = textbox1.GetRectFromCharacterIndex(target_cpos);
  var first_char_rect = textbox1.GetRectFromCharacterIndex(0);
  textbox1.ScrollToVerticalOffset(
   target_char_rect.Top - 
   first_char_rect.Top
 );
}
```

I found out if Wrapping is enabled its more complications:

```
private void TextBoxGotoLine(TextBox textbox1, int linenum)
{
  // int Linenum is the Absolute Line, not including
  //   effect of Textbox Wrapping.

 if (textbox1.TextWrapping == TextWrapping.Wrap)
 {
   // If textbox Wrapping is on, we need to
   // Correct the Linenum for Wrapping which adds extra lines
   int cidx = 0;
   bool found = false;
   int ln = 0;
   char[] tmp = textbox1.Text.ToCharArray();
   for (cidx = 0; cidx < tmp.Length; cidx++)
   {
     if (tmp[cidx] == '\n')
     {
       ln++;
     }
     if (ln == linenum)
     {
       found = true;
       break;
     }
   }
   if (!found) 
     return;

   linenum = textbox1.GetLineIndexFromCharacterIndex(cidx+1);
 }

 // Non-Wrapping TextBox
 var target_cpos = textbox1.GetCharacterIndexFromLineIndex(linenum);
 var target_char_rect = textbox1.GetRectFromCharacterIndex(target_cpos);
 var first_char_rect = textbox1.GetRectFromCharacterIndex(0);
            textbox1.ScrollToVerticalOffset(target_char_rect.Top - first_char_rect.Top);
}
```