# Single-line wpf textbox horizontal scroll to end

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

I have a templated listbox which template among other things contains a wpf textbox too. The data is provided to the listbox through ItemsSource.

The textboxes display filepaths and these are usally quite long. I want when the textboxes are loaded to show the end of the filepaths.

I tried a combination of `DataContextChanged` event and setting `HorizontalScrollBarVisibility` (using double.max or getting the real char length) but to no success. The DataContextChanged seems to be the correct event to use as it fires on each setting of the ItemsSource.

Edit:

Here is sample code to show when the suggestion by Lester works and when it doesnt. I am trying to have it work when the text is set through binding.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfAppTest.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
    Loaded="LoadedHandler">
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <TextBox Name="tbb" Width="50" Height="20" Text="{Binding Path=Str}"
             IsReadOnly="True" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0"
             DataContextChanged="ContextChangedHandler"/>
    <ListBox SelectionMode="Single" x:Name="listBox" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1"
             VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBox Width="50" Height="20" Text="{Binding Path=Str}"
                         IsReadOnly="True"
                         DataContextChanged="ContextChangedHandler"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
</Grid>
```

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent(); 

        var obj = new SomeClass
                      {
                          Str = "qwetyuiuropqo[psdal;dkas;ldamzxn m,cnz128391"
                      };
        listBox.ItemsSource = new List<SomeClass> { obj };
        tbb.DataContext = obj;
    }

    public class SomeClass
    {
        public string Str { get; set; }
    }

    private void LoadedHandler(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var obj = new SomeClass
        {
            Str = "qwetyuiuropqo[psdal;dkas;ldamzxn m,cnz128391"
        };
        listBox.ItemsSource = new List<SomeClass> { obj };
        tbb.DataContext = obj;
    }

    private void ContextChangedHandler(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var textBox = sender as TextBox;
        if (textBox == null) return;

        textBox.CaretIndex = textBox.Text.Length;
        var rect = textBox.GetRectFromCharacterIndex(textBox.CaretIndex);
        textBox.ScrollToHorizontalOffset(rect.Right);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code that you tried?  Thanks.

Comment: You are looking for more than just TextWrapping?  You want to trim the beginning?

Comment: You do know TextBlock has a TextTrimming property but it trims from the right.  If you only want the literal end you could have a property that only return the filename and not the full path.

Comment: When text so long not to fit in the visible area of the textbox is input, by default, the text is shown from its beginning, and it is needed to select it and scroll right to see the end of a filepath. I am trying to have the end of the text shown within the textbox at first.

Comment: I solved this by manually moving down to the correct position. You can look at the code I used here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5262124/wpf-textbox-scrolltoline-not-updating-if-visible

Answer (score 5):

This code worked for me for scrolling to the end of the TextBox (taken from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4056132/389966)):

```
textBox.CaretIndex = textBox.Text.Length;
var rect = textBox.GetRectFromCharacterIndex(textBox.CaretIndex);
textBox.ScrollToHorizontalOffset(rect.Right);
```

Comment: Now, look at my code snippet above. If these three lines are in a Window.Loaded EventHandler then it all works (no need for tb.Focus() too)! However, in my situation I would needed to use textbox.DataContextChanged handler or similar rather than for the Window.Loaded event. Then it does not.

Answer (score 0):

Solution is to change DataContextChanged event with Loaded so that proper notifications are received for the textbox.