# WPF TextBox ScrollToLine Method First scolling to non-visible, and then to visibe

Tags: c#, wpf

For the WPF TextBox UI Controll,  the ScrollToLine() method has a single parameter, which accepts an integer value. This value is the line number that you wish to show, where line zero is the first line of text. **If the line of text is already visible, the TextBox does not scroll**. If it is out of view, the content is scrolled by the minimum amount necessary in order to display the line."

Basically, I don't want this behavior, i want it to always scroll even if its visible.  So I wrote this code to test a work around.

Let's say I have a XML:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Loaded="Window_Loaded"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"  DockPanel.Dock="Top" Background="Aqua">
            <TextBox Name="linenum" Width="80" Text="0"/>
            <Button Name="Go" Content="Go" Click="Go_Click"/>
        </StackPanel>

        <TextBox Name="textbox1" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"/>

    </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

and i have c#:

```cs
using System.Windows;

namespace WpfApp1
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            string text1 = "";
            for(int i=0; i < 10000; i++)
            {
                text1 = text1 + i.ToString() + "\n";
            }
            textbox1.Text = text1;
        }

        private void Go_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            int ilinenum = int.Parse(linenum.Text);
            textbox1.ScrollToLine(textbox1.LineCount-1);
            textbox1.ScrollToLine(ilinenum);
        }
    }
}
```

Basically, I want to scroll to line 10, by first scrolling to a non-visual portion of the TextBox, (aka. the end of the TextBox), and then scroll immediately back to the line 10 when clicking the "Go" Button.

Why doesn't this work?  when I enter 10, its scrolls to the end, and ignores the second call to ScrollToLine.

my test is as folllows, start with scroller positioned at line 0.  enter 10 in textbox and click go.  observe above behavior.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [WPF TextBox ScrollToLine not updating if visible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5262124/wpf-textbox-scrolltoline-not-updating-if-visible)

Answer (score 1):

try the folowing:

```
private void Go_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        int ilinenum = int.Parse(linenum.Text);
        var target_char_rect = textbox1.GetRectFromCharacterIndex(
        textbox1.GetCharacterIndexFromLineIndex(ilinenum));
        var first_char_rect = textbox1.GetRectFromCharacterIndex(0);
        textbox1.ScrollToVerticalOffset(target_char_rect.Top-first_char_rect.Top);
    }
```

Comment: Just tried it.  That works beautifully!  Thanks.